# How to read the recommendations from DBA?

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization, sql-execution-plan

I want to know / learn the difference between NESTED LOOPS and Hash join. for this purpose I posted this question. The query and explain plan are very lengthy, so these are not posted here.

I have the following recommendations by DBA, can anyone explain what is needed by the new execution plan?

**Oraiginal Execution plan 1**
[image]

**New Execution plan 1**
[image]

I think its need to remove the NESTED LOOPS, how to remove these NESTED LOOPS?

Comment: Have you considered talking to your DBA and asking them what they mean? It's a old trick but it just might work.

Comment: which one is fast? hash or NESTED LOOPS, why the DBA recommends to remove NESTED LOOPS?

Comment: @Muhammad In general NESTED LOOPs is best when selecting a small percentage of the rows from a table, and HASH JOIN is best when selecting a large percentage of the rows.  But this is a complicated subject and a lot more information is necessary to answer this.  For starters, it would help to post the entire explain plan in the standard format, using `explain plan for select ...` and then `select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);`.  Also, what is the query, and how did the DBA make the change?  Was it a code change, statistics, plan management, etc.

Comment: @JonHeller I want to know the difference between NESTED LOOPS and hash join, My Query and the explain plan is very lengthy, so that is not added here.

Comment: @JonHeller good information regarding the NESTED LOOPs and hash join. My query is an insert statement which query and insert more than 100,000 records. so in my case the NESTED LOOP is very expensive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "**Oraiginal Execution plan**" have NESTED LOOPS on WIP.WIP_OPERATIONS_U1 (index) this means we have some iteration on this index, and the "**New Execution plan**" is recommending to remove that iterations.

In my opinion the NESTED LOOPS are costly compare to hash join.